# Calculating limits

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Okay, I'm stuck with this question. We are supposed to make a graph of a function (but that's not my problem):

$$f(x)=\frac{5(x-2)}{x^2}$$

*[First, I have to determine points where the function is equal to zero, then first derivative and solutions for first derivative (when it's equal to 0) and so on. The last step is to make asymptotes, and **check with limits** (I have only 1 example of this so I'm not sure about this one).]*

What we do is determine certain points, like edge points of the domain, stationary points (x-axis of the extremes), infinities(+ and -) and I'm not sure what other points...

So what I have to do is determine this limes:

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{5(x-2)}{x^2}
=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\left(\frac5x-\frac{10}{x^2}\right)=0
$$

This should equal to $0^+$ according to my graph, and Wolfram Alpha, **how do I determine this** by some math magic trick. Maybe if I looked at it like it's obviously bigger than $0$, so it's $0^+$.

(Our example was this one: $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}(x^2/(x^2-1))$ and here he told us that the denominator is obviously smaller than the numerator, therefore, it's greater than $1$ (the solution is $1^+$).)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x > \dfrac{5}{2}$ then $\dfrac{5(x - 2)}{x^2} > \dfrac{x}{x^2} = \dfrac{1}{x} > 0$, and $\dfrac{5(x - 2)}{x^2} < \dfrac{5x}{x^2} = \dfrac{5}{x}$, and that: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty} \dfrac{1}{x} = 0^+ = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty} \dfrac{5}{x}$. So by squeeze theorem: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty} \dfrac{5(x - 2)}{x^2} = 0^+ ( = 0 )$

Comment: I feel stupid for asking this easy question after I've figured it out. (I know I should've deleted it, but yeah...) Ty anyways.

Answer (score 1):

It follows because

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^p} = 0 $$

for $p \geq 1 $

Comment: I'm asking about  $ 0^+$ or $0^-$.